# Given an integer, w, find n and k such that n^k = w

Tags: algorithm, math, exponential, exponent

I'm working on a Uva problem (#107) and I know I have the right answer, and now I just need to optimise it so it doesn't time out. I believe this snippet is the culprit. I need to find n and k such that n^k = working. I tried making my own power function to speed it up but that didn't help. What are some ways to quickly calculate a base and exponent to equal a given value?

```
N = 2;
for(int i = 1; i < range; i++){
    result = pow(N, i);

    if(result > working){
        i = 1;
        N++;
    }

    if(result == working){
        k = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: You might first check that `working % i == 0`..

Comment: Sounds like you have an algorithmic problem.

Comment: How about `n=w, k=1`?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **k >= 2** and limit `N` with `sqrt(w)`, start `i` with `2` in the loop. If solution is not found then **k = 1**, **n = w**. Also you do not need `pow`, you could multiply intermediate product by `N` on each iteration.